# Ruby & Rails visual tests, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

Im new to Ruby and Rails and I`m trying to establish a test suite for my sample project. But the point is that I would like to take this working as in my old platform: Java. Let me explain...

In Java, I would choose Apache Selenium, record my mouse movements and keyboard typing, and with that behaviour recorded in my app, I would run my tests continuously. If there`s any errors raised, they would be reported to me immediately.

I would like to use this kind of tool integrated with my project, because I`m sorry, but I really don`t believe that my tests would be better made in code. So, I would like:
- Change my mind to see how code made tests could be better than anything
- Use this kind of visual tool in my tests environments.

Could anybody tell me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a tool which records the mouse clicks and movements but yes there is testing framework which allows you to do view testing in your language visual testing. For that you may use `Capybara and Selenium`. You can write code which page to visit what should be filled in the text box or where should it click and so on. Here are some links which may help you:

http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/116-selenium

And here is the gem `capybara`:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Hope this helps.